# Grid View is visible in design mode but invisible on execution in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net aspx with the code as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="globalWrapper">
           <div class="Header">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownState" runat="server" class="Controls">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" Text="Choose From Date..." class="Controls"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnFromDate" runat="server" Text="..." class="btnDate" OnClick="btnFromDate_Click" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Text="Choose To Date..." class="Controls"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnToDate" runat="server" Text="..." class="btnDate" OnClick="btnToDate_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btnControls" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" runat="server" Text="Log Out" class="btnControls" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" />
            </div>


             <div class="calendarFromDate">
                 <asp:Calendar ID="calendarFromDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                     BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" 
                     DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
                     ForeColor="#003399" Height="200px" Visible="False" Width="220px" 
                     onselectionchanged="calendarFromDate_SelectionChanged">
                     <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
                     <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                     <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                     <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                     <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
                     <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" 
                         Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Height="25px" />
                     <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
                     <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
                 </asp:Calendar>
            </div>


            <div class="calendarToDate">
                <asp:Calendar ID="calendarToDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" 
                    DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
                    ForeColor="#003399" Height="200px" Visible="False" Width="220px" 
                    onselectionchanged="calendarToDate_SelectionChanged">
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" 
                        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Height="25px" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>

            <div class="Contents">
                <div class="gridView">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gridStateErrorData" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666"
                        BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="chart_container" class="chartContainer" runat="server">
            </div>

            <asp:Literal ID="literalMapIndia" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

       </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFromDate" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnToDate" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropDownState" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLogout" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

On **Submit** button click based on logic it is fetching the data from **SQL Server 2008**  and should display it in **GridView**. But on execution I'm unable to see the **GridView** on web page. However if I switch to design mode in visual studio I can pretty much see the **GridView** there.

I tried removing the division's **calendarFromDate** and **calendarToDate** the **GridView** works fine. I think these div's are actually hiding the underlying **GridView**. I tried using ***"z-index = -1"*** as style attribute to them but no change. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance

My CSS is as below:

```
body 
{
    background: #B4C8E1;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}

.globalWrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color : #6E83B6;
}

.Header
{
    width : 99%;
    margin-left:0.5%;
    border:2px solid black;
    height: 45px;
    background-color:Blue;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Controls
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:6%;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}

.btnControls
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:6%;
    width: 8%;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.btnDate
{
    width:3%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}


.calendarFromDate
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:29%;
    float:left;
    width:17%;
}

.calendarToDate
{
    position:relative;
    margin-right:32%;
    float:right;
    width:17%;
}

.Contents
{
    width: 99%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left:0.5%;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.gridView
{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:25%;
    text-align:center;
}

.chartContainer
{
    width:90%;
    height:600px;
    margin-left:5%; 
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Edit : Code Behind

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        chart_container.Visible = false;


        List<StateData> stateData = new List<StateData>();
        DataAccessLayer data = new DataAccessLayer();

        stateData = data.getStateData(dropDownState.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(), txtFromDate.Text.ToString(), txtToDate.Text.ToString());
        gridStateErrorData.DataSource = stateData;
        gridStateErrorData.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: First check if the data is there in the `GridView` data source. And check if you are calling `gridStateErrorData.DataBind();` after assigning datasource.

Comment: @Bharadwaj thanks, but yes I did that. I traced my code and the data is coming fine. Like I said if I just hide the two division tags calendarFromDate and calendarToDate it displays the GridView with data just fine

Comment: Set the [GridView.EmptyDataText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(v=vs.110).aspx) property so you can verify that the gv is really getting data.

Comment: @mason 14, I've added the GridView.EmptyDataText property. That's not the issue. Like I said if I just comment out the two calendar control holding div's and hard code the date, grid view is visible with data...

Answer (score 0):

I think two divisions calendarFromDate and calendarToDate are hiding the regarding division as you said.

Try adding specific height and float property to Contents and gridView classes in your css code.

```
    .Contents
    {
        width: 99%;
        height: 500px;
        margin-left:0.5%;
        border:2px solid black;
        float:left;
    }

    .gridView
    {
        width:50%;
        height:600px;
        margin-left:25%;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: @ Ugur thanks for your time and solution. I tried it but still same, no change